# Release version of Ionic 1 on android 4.4 has cors errors

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, cors

am currently having a problem with Ionic 1 when using a release build on android 4.4. I keep getting a `cors` error. In addition am using a node.js back end with `cors` requests specified in it already. This is the error am seeing so far:

SEC7121: [CORS] The origin 'http://localhost:8100' found `*` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header when the credentials mode was `include` for cross-origin  resource at 'https://www.slywolf.co.za/api/auth/signin'.

Any assistance regarding this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add This as a middle ware in your node.js server.
This will allow cross origin request with Credentials

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8100");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST,PATCH, DELETE, PUT");
         res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
        next();
    });
```

Comment: I have this as follows:  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); but for some weird reason android 4 is the only one with this issue. Android versions 6 upwards are fine

Comment: So error in there or not After Putting "http://localhost:8100" instead of * ?

Comment: @ PrashantGupta give me a few minutes to adjust the server settings quick